# Fetch parent data based on conditions on child and its child

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, where-clause

I have the following table structure:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------------------------+
| users | shows | show_user | user_notification_tokens |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id    | id    | id        | id                       |
|       |       | user_id   | user_id                  |
|       |       | show_id   | token                    |
|       |       |           | platform                 |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

User can subscribe to many shows and show can be subscribed by many users which is the `show_user` table. 
Users can have many tokens in `user_notification_tokens` table.

I need to get tokens of subscribed users to certain show.

I've tried the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT `token` 
FROM `user_notification_tokens`
WHERE `platform` = 'iOS' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT `id` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `user_notification_tokens`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT* 
        FROM `shows` 
        INNER JOIN `show_user` 
        ON `shows`.`id` = `show_user`.`show_id` 
        WHERE `users`.`id` = `show_user`.`user_id` 
        AND `shows`.`id` = 15
    )
)
```

The result is fine, however it takes 3.8019 seconds to load, my results count is 716 which will be much much more in the future.

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve this query?

Comment: This sounds like it may only require a simple join between `show_user` and `user_notification_tokens`. Can you post a sample of rows from each of these tables together with a sample of the rows you expect your query to produce from those inputs?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks a lot, GMB provided a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple JOIN should meet your requirement:

```
SELECT unt.token
FROM user_notification_tokens unt
INNER JOIN show_user su ON su.user_id = unt.user_id AND su.show_id = ?
WHERE unt.platform = 'iOS'
```

You can replace the question mark with the id of the show that you are looking for.

This assumes that each user can only subscribe once to each show (else you would get duplicates), which seems relevant given the information you provided.

Comment: Welcome @MahmoudTarek!